# Parameter not passed through well

Tags: linux, bash, unix, passwords

I created a function for crypting passwords. But the first parameter is not passed through well. `crypt_pass "a"` outputs the same as `crypt_pass "b"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
crypt_pass() {
    echo $(perl -e'print crypt($1, "aa")')
}
```

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding the parameter inside a perl script can lead to trouble if there are characters special to perl in the parameter value.  Best to do something like

```
crypt_pass() {
    echo $(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "aa")' "$1")
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's better, I totally forgot this issue in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without having tested it, my guess would be that inside `'` quotes, no variable substitution is performed, and the `$1` is passed literally.

Comment: Yep, `$1` is interpreted as a Perl variable, not as a Bash one.

Comment: Hmm, how can it be concatenated right? I tried `crypt('.$1.')`, but that didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the Perl code in double quotes, this way bash can substitute its `$1` before the string is passed to the Perl interpreter.

```
crypt_pass() {
    echo $(perl -e"print crypt($1, \"aa\")")
}
```

Since in Perl you can use single quotes for a string, you can avoid the escaping by just using single quotes, so it would become a bit cleaner:

```
crypt_pass() {
    echo $(perl -e"print crypt($1, 'aa')")
}
```